# Importing multiple images from gallery into xamarin forms application and display them on my content page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, media, photo, plugin.media.crossmedia

My use case requires the user to select multiple photos from his device gallery and display the selected images as a gridview inside my xamarin forms application. I already have done the Take photo using the device camera and display the photo taken on the app, but this is just one photo at a time. The code for take photo is as below.

```
 public async void DoTakePhoto()
    {
      try
      {
        VisualState = State.Loading;

        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
          return;
        }
       
        MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
          
          SaveToAlbum = true,
          Directory = "App Photo Folder",
          MaxWidthHeight = 2048,
          CompressionQuality = 50,
          PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
        });
       
        if (file == null && ImageSource == null)
        {
         
          return;
        }
        else if (file == null)
        {
         
          return;
        }
        
        MediaWithFile = new MediumWithFile(m_ExifDataParser) {
          Id = new Guid(),
          Data = file,
          Path = file.Path,
          AlbumPath = file.AlbumPath,
          Version = 1
        };
      
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        DisplayAlert("B5", ex.ToString(), "B5");
        
        return;
      }
      finally
      {
        VisualState = State.None;
      }
    }
```

And i am having a bindable **ImageSource** variable as follows:

```
public ImageSource ImageSource =>  MediaWithFile?.Data == null ? null : ImageSource.FromFile(MediaWithFile.Data.Path);
```

I am displaying the clicked photo on my UI using the following code:

```
<Frame Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   Padding="0"
                   CornerRadius="8">
          <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
        </Frame>
```

Is there a way to upload multiple images from gallery and display them using the same Crossmedia plugin. Any idea on this is appreciated.

Comment: there are numerous existing questions on this subject - https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+select+multiple+image+from+gallery+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: What have you tried and what is the exact problem did you meet ?